# How to extract data from a table With no Style/Class/ID information

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xpath

i want to parse specific table for scrapping. the code of the table is given below..

```
<table class="NormalText" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" width="100%" border="0"
    bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <tr>
        <td width="108" align="center">
            Stock No.
        </td>
        <td width="108" align="center">
            <span id="invModule_grid_row18_lblMileage">Mileage</span>
        </td>
        <td width="108" align="center">

            Color
        </td>
        <td width="76" align="center">
            Interior
        </td>
        <td width="104" align="center">
            Transmission
        </td>
        <td width="110" align="center">
            Engine
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="108" align="center">
            1204
        </td>
        <td width="108" align="center">
            161,328
        </td>
        <td width="108" align="center">
            Tan
        </td>

        <td width="76" align="center">
            Leather   
        </td>
        <td width="104" align="center">
            Automatic
        </td>
        <td width="110" align="center">
            3.5L V6 DOHC 16V
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="7" height="7">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the output i want is

> 1194  56,200  Blue    Vinyl   5 Speed     6.8L V10 SOHC 30V

**Questions**

Which parsing Technique /Parser is best for this? PHPQuery, simplehtmlparse or xpath?

I am more familiar with domDocument, xpath and php, can it be done using xPath?

if yes, what will be xPath? (I am confused as my required data is in td and td tag has no id or class information attached. Also, on the uper row, which is basically a heading row, td are ther too)

Please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XPath

The following example selects the text from all the td nodes in a table row in a table:

```
//table/tr[position()>1]/td/text()
```

### You will have to know one of two things if there are other tables on the page:

Gets the last table:

```
//table[last()]/tr[position()>1]/td/text()
```

Gets the third table:

```
//table[2]/tr[position()>1]/td/text()
```

Gets a table based on an attribute, in this case, when class="NormalText":

```
//table[@class='NormalText']/tr[position()>1]/td/text()
```

Comment: on the page, there are other tables too. and what i guess, if i use the code you provide, it will select data from each of td tag, but i dont want to get the data td tags from first tr tag

Comment: and that too..if more than 1 table are there, i can use loop or style information on this

Comment: Ok, this will skip the first tr now.

Comment: can i get it in array? Or can i use First row's elements as key and 2nd rows elements as values?